# Meteor node.js latest version

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Why does Meteor use **node.js 4.8.2** while the **latest version** of node.js is **7.7.3**?

```
$ node --version
    v7.7.3

$ meteor node --version
    v4.8.2
```

Comment: Version 7 is not a LTS. They are progressively updating node, but since it's a big project upgrading all dependencies it's not easy. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/616761daf35f602308258246524def787bffa8fc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**: According to the [PR for Meteor 1.6](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8728#issuecomment-306313318) , it will pack Node v8.

---

Because Meteor is a big framework and is hard to keep such a big framework stable and up to date with Node.

As Meteor 1.5 has been just released, it is developed on Node v4.

According to [Ben from the MDG](https://blog.meteor.com/announcing-meteor-1-5-b82be66571bb), the bundled version of Node for Meteor will be updated to the next [LTS (Node v6)](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS) on the next Meteor 1.6 release.

> The plan for Meteor 1.6 is simple: upgrade Meteor from Node 4 to Node 6, now that Node 4 no longer enjoys long-term support (LTS), and Node 6 is the official stable version. Much of this work has already happened in parallel with Meteor 1.5, so we anticipate a much shorter release cycle for Meteor 1.6. Please see this pull request if you want to get involved, as your help will surely speed that effort along.

Comment: Per the Meteor PR announcing 1.6, they'll be going straight to Node 8!

Comment: You are right! I'll update my answer. Thanks for the update!